# How to prevent JPopUpMenu disappearing when checking checkboxes in it?

Tags: swing, jcheckbox, jpopupmenu

I want to use `JCheckBoxMenuItem`s in a `JPopupMenu`. It works, but the problem is that the popup menu disappears when a checkbox item has been checked or unchecked. So if one wants to check/uncheck several items, the popup needs to be launched repeatedly, which is irritating.

Curiously, if I use just plain `JCheckBox` items in the menu (instead of `JCheckBoxMenuItem`s), the behavior is just as it should be: the popup stays there and the checkboxes can be checked/unchecked. Once done, the popup can be closed just by clicking outside it.

How do I make the popup to behave like that when the items there are `JCheckBoxMenuItem`s? I would prefer using `JCheckBoxMenuItem`s because of their looks.

Comment: I think this is a bug and should be fixed by the Swing library authors, rather than avoided using workarounds. The only problem is, that Java developpers rather find excuses than fix their bugs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, found working answer from http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5432911. Basically, create a custom UI:

```
public class StayOpenCheckBoxMenuItemUI extends BasicCheckBoxMenuItemUI {

   @Override
   protected void doClick(MenuSelectionManager msm) {
      menuItem.doClick(0);
   }

   public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c) {
      return new StayOpenCheckBoxMenuItemUI();
   }
}
```

And set it in the `JCheckBoxMenuItem`:

```
myJCheckBoxMenuItem.setUI(new StayOpenCheckBoxMenuItemUI());
```

Don't know if this is the most elegant possible solution, but works perfectly.

Comment: "working answer" refers to link to forums sun com which is broken

Comment: Additional information on this solution can be found here: http://www.coderanch.com/t/497325/GUI/java/keep-popup-while-clicking-JCheckBoxMenuItem

Answer (score 3):

I ran into an issue with the nice Joonas Pulakka's answer because the "UIManager lookandFeel" was ignored.

I found the nice trick below on http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/09/12/keeping-menus-open/

The point is to reopen immediatly the menu after it has been closed, it's invisible and keep the application look and feel and behavior.

```
public class StayOpenCBItem extends JCheckBoxMenuItem {

    private static MenuElement[] path;

    {
        getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                if (getModel().isArmed() && isShowing()) {
                    path = MenuSelectionManager.defaultManager().getSelectedPath();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public StayOpenCBItem(String text) {
        super(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void doClick(int pressTime) {
        super.doClick(pressTime);
        MenuSelectionManager.defaultManager().setSelectedPath(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: For me, this does not work when used in a `JPopupMenu`. Quoting author from the article’s comments “The enhancements provided here were not intended to work with any kind of popup menu.”

Answer (score 2):

I found a much easier solution for this problem

```
JCheckBoxMenuItem menuItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("sample");
menuItem.putClientProperty("CheckBoxMenuItem.doNotCloseOnMouseClick", Boolean.TRUE);
```

I found this solution while reading the code from

```
BasicMenuItemUI.doNotCloseOnMouseClick()
```